# Respondging time needed after suspend/hibernate

Tags: suspend, hibernate, responsiveness

Whenever I come back to my laptop from Suspend/Hibernate, my laptop takes a bit of time before it starts to respond. What I mean is, the screen starts, then I enter my password, and the desktop loads in. Then, I can't use the keyboard/mouse for a few seconds. Only then I can start using my laptop again. What can I do to fix it? Sometimes, the time gap is more than just a few seconds.

**Specs:**
Software: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (64-bit) (Wayland)
Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-7020U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4
Graphics: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2F)